# Instantiation of a Non-static Class(context) in a Static method with a Constructor taking type Object as parameter

Tags: c#

The `ConsultantContext class` is a basic setup for the local database while the `public TemplateGenerator(ConsultantContext context)` constructor is needed for `_context` to not be null. However this doesn't come with it downsides. When you try to call the non-static method `List<Consultant> GetById(int id)` within a static method `GetHTMLString()`,  you will find that the class name must be instantiated `TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator();` to access is methods and varables.
However, the constructor is asking for a argument to be given in the parentheses.

And I get

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of TemplateGenerator.TemplateGenerator(ConsultantContext)

First attempt:

```
TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator(context); // Does not exist 
TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator(this.context); // not valid iin a static property
TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator(ConsultantContext context); // Not a valid type apperantly
```

Second attempt:
Reading and searching for hours on StackOverflow about accessing methods which are non-static in static methods with the conclusion that none of them deal with parameters in parantheses within the constructors unless it is very basic parameters like a string or a int, not a own created object.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using ConsultantData;
  using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

  namespace PDF_Generator.Utility
  {
   public class TemplateGenerator : Consultant
   {
    private ConsultantContext _context;

    public TemplateGenerator(ConsultantContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private List<Consultant> GetById(int id)
    {
        return new List<Consultant>
        {

        _context.Consultants
        .Include(asset => asset.IsAvailable)
        .Include(asset => asset.FirstName)
        .Include(asset => asset.Skills)
        .Include(asset => asset.YearsOfJobExperience)
        .FirstOrDefault(asset => asset.Id == id)

        };
    }

    public static string GetHTMLString()
    {
        TemplateGenerator generator = new TemplateGenerator();
        var consultantInfo = generator.GetById(0); // Hardcoded number 0 just to try selecting from database 
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"
                         <html>
                             <head>
                             </head>
                             <body>
                                 <div class='header'><h1>This is the generated PDF report!!!</h1></div>
                                 <table align='center'>
                                     <tr>
                                         <th>Is_Available</th>
                                         <th>FirstName</th>
                                         <th>Skills</th>
                                         <th>YearsOfJobExperience</th>
                                         <th>id</th>
                                     </tr>");

        foreach (var consultant in consultantInfo)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(@"<tr>
                                     <td>{0}</td>
                                     <td>{1}</td>
                                     <td>{2}</td>
                                     <td>{3}</td>
                                   </tr>", consultant.IsAvailable,
                                      consultant.FirstName,
                                      consultant.Skills,
                                      consultant.YearsOfJobExperience,
                                      consultant.Id);
        }

        sb.Append(@"
                                 </table>
                             </body>
                         </html>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

  // CONVERTING AND GENERATING A PDF DOCUMENT FROM HTML CODE IN             
  // IN method HtmlContent = TemplateGenerator.GetHTMLString() BELOW.

using DinkToPdf;
using DinkToPdf.Contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using PDF_Generator.Utility;

namespace PDF_Generator.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PdfCreatorController : ControllerBase
{

    private IConverter _converter;        

    public PdfCreatorController(IConverter converter)
    {
        _converter = converter;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreatePDF()
    {
        var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
        {
            ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
            Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
            Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
            DocumentTitle = "PDF Report",
            //Out = @"D:\PDFCreator\Employee_Report.pdf"  USE THIS PROPERTY TO SAVE PDF TO A PROVIDED LOCATION
        };

        var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
        {
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = TemplateGenerator.GetHTMLString(),
            //Page = "https://code-maze.com/", USE THIS PROPERTY TO GENERATE PDF CONTENT FROM AN HTML PAGE
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8", UserStyleSheet =  Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets", "styles.css") },
            HeaderSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
            FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Line = true, Center = "Report Footer" }
```

};

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using ConsultantData.Models;

    namespace ConsultantData
    {
         public class ConsultantContext : DbContext
         {
         public ConsultantContext(DbContextOptions options) :                                                                                                                                   
         base(options) {}
         public DbSet<Consultant> Consultants { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Recruiter> Recruiters { get; set; }
         }
    }
```

Which parameter should be passed in this scenario?
Is there a way to access this method? From the same class in a static method or from a different class within the same namespace? I expect the static method **GetHTMLString()** to store the variables availability, firstname, skills, years of job experience in the HTML element.

Comment: Why is `GetHTMLString` static?

Comment: When removing static from method:
An object reference is required for non-static field, method or property (TemplateGenerator.GetHTMLString). And so creating an instance is what I've tried to do but following happens:
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of TemplateGenerator.TemplateGenerator(ConsultantContext)

Comment: If the above is your actual code, at least one problem might just be case sensitivity. If the class is called `TemplateGenerator` you can't instantiate `Templategenerator` (lower-case G) because there's no such class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding of class members and instance members; maybe even objects altogether. Your `GetHTMLString` method is a class member because you have declared it as `static`. Class members cannot access instance members.

The following do not work when called from inside `GetHTMLString` because:

1) `context` is an instance member, you cannot access instance members from class members because there is no instance to access:

```
TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator(context); // Does not exist
```

2) `this` is how an instance refers to itself but a class is not an instance.

```
TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator(this.context); // not valid iin a static property
```

3) This is just not syntactically correct:

```
TemplateGenerator generator = new Templategenerator(ConsultantContext context); // Not a valid type apperantly
```

How you decide to solve this depends on how you want to design your `TemplateGenerator`. If you want to maintain it as a non-static class then remove `static` from `GetHTMLString` and instead of instantiating a `TemplateGenerator` in `GetHTMLString` simply call `this.GetById(0)`. If you go with this approach you will have to instantiate (e.g. new up or inject) a member of `TemplateGenerator` before you can call `GetHTMLString`. Your other option is to convert `TemplateGenerator` to a static class, change `GetById` to a static method, remove the constructor and instance members, and pass your dependency (i.e. `ConsultantContext`) as a parameter.

Comment: I will make sure to read about the above topics. Thank you Jason for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

```
TemplateGenerator generator = new TemplateGenerator();
```

Is not valid.  Your constructor signature:

```
public TemplateGenerator(ConsultantContext context)
```

requires you to pass a `ConsultantContext`.

Comment: Is this signature within the method GetHTMLString()? Because the public modifier is not valid for this item, neither do I have a clue on what value to return of type  ConsultantContext.